# Unique names with employee department

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aginity

I have an employee database and employees are appearing multiple times.

- Some instances of same employee has employee department, where as in some other instances, employee department is missing. For this I need to find distinct of employee name along with employee department.
- Some employees do not have any employee department at all. For this I need to only find distinct employee name.

My query:

```
------for each unique employee, find department
--select columns
select 
  a.employee_name,b.employee_dept
from
  --unique employee names
  (
   select 
     distinct employee_name 
   from 
     employeeDB 
   where 
     employee_name is not null and employee_name != ''
   order by employee_name asc
  ) as a,
  --employee name and employee dept sorted
  (
  select 
     employee_name,employee_dept 
   from 
     employeeDB 
   where employee_name is not null and employee_name != ''
   order by employee_name asc, employee_dept desc
  ) as b
--condition for join
where
  a.employee_name = b.employee_name
order by a.employee_name asc, b.employee_dept desc
limit 1000
```

I am not sure why results are not returning unique results. i am getting results similar to below

```
Name  Dept
A     DepA
A     DepB
A   
B     DepA
B   
C     DepZ
D   
E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get all unique names (by grouping it) and grabs the (alphabetically) highest `employee_dept` it can find for each

```
select employee_name, max(employee_dept) as dept
from employeeDB 
where employee_name is not null and employee_name != ''
group by employee_name
order by employee_name asc
limit 1000
```

Comment: Sorry, i re-phrased my question. second column is department name.

Comment: OK, then rename it in my query.

Comment: The problem is department is not a numeric query, its rather a name field and max might not give the required result on string data

Comment: let me try this query then. Thanks!!

Comment: it gave me error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762587/redshift-querying-error-xx000-disk-full-redshift/

Comment: That error has nothing to do with this query. Your hard disk is full. Make space